# Issue with JSON in a PHP SQL query

Tags: php, mysql, json

I have a server.php file which is supposed to return a table of ints.
Each one of these ints is linked to a key (some ints can have the same key). The table needs to only contain ints linked to a specific key.

To get one of these key, i need to have another key as a parameter.

So the process is :

The server is called by an $http.post (i'm using AngularJS) :

```
$http.post('server.php', {"data" : parameterKey, "serverFlag" : 4})
```

(serverFlag is not yet used, and parameterKey is a string)

I then use parameterKey to get anotherKey :

```
$data = file_get_contents("php://input");
$objData = json_decode($data);

$conn = new PDO(/*something*/);
$outp = [];

$anotherKey  = $conn->query("SELECT anotherKey FROM myTable1 WHERE parameterKey = $objData->data");
$anotherKey  = $anotherKey ->fetch();
```

Then, i use anotherKey to gather all the ints linked to this key :

```
$result = $conn->query("SELECT myInt FROM myTable2 WHERE id = $anotherKey  ORDER BY myInt ASC");
while($rs = $result->fetch()) {
        if ($outp != "") {
            array_push($outp,$rs["myInt"]);
        }
}

$outp =json_encode($outp);
echo($outp);
```

(I don't know if I have made myself very clear so far...)

So i have a JSON error when running this :

```
Error: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data
```

I'm not really sure where the error is. Any ideas ?

### EDIT

I have the following error :

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch() on boolean in C:\wamp64  \www\tests\server.php on line <i>47</i> 
(line 47 =  $anotherKey  = $anotherKey ->fetch();)
```

Comment: What output are you getting in $data after file_get_contents ?

Comment: use this  `$objData['data']` in your query

Comment: Using `$objData['data']` is not working.

I'm new to webdev, so how can i get the content of $data ?

Comment: Check if $_POST["data"] contains what you need. The post may automatically convert to object to post variables instead of just passing a JSON.

Comment: I don't think that's the issue. I used a very similar querry :
`"SELECT id_text FROM association WHERE id_text LIKE '%".$objData->data."%' "` which is working fine.

Comment: I noticed an error in the response sent by the server.
I edited my question.

Comment: I believe that in this line `$anotherKey  = $anotherKey ->fetch();` you shouldn't reuse `$anotherKey` variable

Comment: I tried with another variable, but got the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

You are interpolating the string the wrong way:

```
$anotherKey  = $conn->query("SELECT anotherKey FROM myTable1 WHERE parameterKey = $objData->data");
```

Note how you are calling `$objData->data` directly. You should do this instead:

```
$anotherKey  = $conn->query("SELECT anotherKey FROM myTable1 WHERE parameterKey = {$objData->data}");
```

In PHP you can only interpolate variables in a string. If you are referring to object properties or array items/dictionary keys, you have to enclose them in `{}`. So this is valid:

```
$myInterpolatedString = "This is a string with a $variable";
```

and this is valid:

```
$myInterpolatedString = "This is a string with a {$object->property}";
```

while this is not:

```
$myIncorrectlyInterpolatedString = "This is a string with $object->property";
```

Edit: on a more security oriented note, you should never feed anything from the input *directly* to a query, since you are exposing yourself to a security threat (SQL injection). Consider using [prepared statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/134099/are-pdo-prepared-statements-sufficient-to-prevent-sql-injection)!

Comment: Thanks for the help. I thinks that's only one of my error though, since i still have the issue mentioned above.

Comment: Then you should try `var_dump`ing `$anotherKey` after the query and see what it looks like. Comment out the rest of the code as well, and use the excellent POSTMan (a Chrome app) to debug your request!

Comment: Taking a look at the documentation (https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php) it states that `PDO::query` returns false on failure, so maybe try dividing your problem into smaller ones and solve each one separately? Try storing your query in a string, debug that to see that it's what you want (and try running it directly on the db through phpMyAdmin or the mysql console), then try again with PDO!

Comment: I see. I found something that could be my big issue.

`$result = $conn->query("SELECT myInt FROM table2");` is returning something, while `$result = $conn->query("SELECT myInt FROM table2 WHERE id = '3dec4242ed76467b9010bba2dcdbed97');` isn't (it's returning an empy table). This is weird, because '3dec4242ed76467b9010bba2dcdbed97' is an id i manually copy pasted from my database. So it should be returning at least the value corresponding to this id...

Comment: What happens if you paste that exact same query in phpMyAdmin or run it through the mysql console?

Comment: The problem is clearly in your query then! Are you sure the column you are looking for is called `id`? You were using `parameterKey` before...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108258/discussion-between-oliviergrech-and-juandemarco).